# Automapper: How to convert a list of ids to a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I want to convert an array of ids from a dto to a list of related objects using AutoMapper, however, the mapping only works one way.

The current setup is the following:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class GroupDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int[] locationIds { get; set; }
}
```

And the code in the `GroupProfile`:

```
CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.locationIds, opt => 
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.Locations.Select(l => l.Id).ToArray()));
```

This code works when I try to convert a `Group` to a `GroupDto`, but not when I try it the other way around. The following error occurs:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
> Mapping types:
> GroupDto -> Group

Also, when I do it without the AutoMapper like below, it just works:

```
Group group = new Group
{
    Name = groupDto.name,
    Locations = _context.Locations
        .Where(l => groupDto.locationIds.Contains(l.Id))
        .ToList()
};
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: In your last code snippet where you did the mapping manually, you can see that you had to use `DbContext` and query the database based on the id's to fetch the entities. So how can automapper map id's to entities without querying the database? You could try to use DbContext in your mapping profile.

Comment: I was wondering the same. The way you're doing it without AutoMapper is a one liner, so elegant/good enough? When required you can do this part manually and use AutoMapper to map rest of properties. At least that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper cannot convert an `int[]` to a `ICollection<Location>`. You need to create a seperate mapping for this.

```
CreateMap<GroupDto, Group>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Locations, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(l => new Location { Id = src }));
```

I haven't tested this snippet so I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The `locationIds` in `GroupDto` are ids that are already present in the database. I need to link them up somehow. When I use your method it will create new entries, which is unwanted behaviour. Any idea?

Comment: You don't have enough info in your Dto. I'd suggest changing the `int[]` to a `LocationDto` that can be mapped to `Location`.

Answer (score 1):

Your AutoMapper doesn't find the mapping from `GroupDto` to `Group`.

1. You need `.ReverseMap()` to support reverse mapping from `Group` to `GroupDto`.
2. Mapping configuration for mapping from `Location` to `int` and vice versa via `.ConstructUsing()`.
3. Modify the mapping for the member `locationIds`.
4. The mapping for the members `id` and `name` may be omitted as AutoMapper will perform the mapping between members by *ignoring case-sensitive*.

```cs
CreateMap<Location, int>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => src.Id);
            
CreateMap<int, Location>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new Location { Id = src });
            
CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.locationIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Locations))
    .ReverseMap();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/meU97c)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the `locationIds` in `GroupDto` are ids that are already present in the database. I need to link them up somehow. When I use your method it will create new entries, which is unwanted behaviour. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm, it is a kind of weird behavior, did you check after mapping from GroupDto to Group, the Location object's ID value does map? While need to review your Location entity and its relationship between Group and Location generated by the EF Core. I believe the new issue mentioned is due to EF Core.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the meaning of *it will create new entries*, the entries is which entity? And the further code how you use mapped Group to store in DB, are you trying to perform the insertion/update?